# What causes this weird behaviour in the randomForest.partialPlot function?

Tags: r

I am using the `randomForest` package (v. 4.6-7) in R 2.15.2. I cannot find the source code for the `partialPlot` function and am trying to figure out exactly what it does (the help file seems to be incomplete.) It is supposed to take the name of a variable `x.var` as an argument:

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)

rf <- randomForest(Species ~., data=iris)
x1 <- "Sepal.Length"
partialPlot(x=rf, pred.data=iris, x.var=x1)
# Error in `[.data.frame`(pred.data, , xname) : undefined columns selected

partialPlot(x=rf, pred.data=iris, x.var=as.character(x1))
# works!

typeof(x1)
# [1] "character"

x1 == as.character(x1)
# TRUE

# Now if I try to wrap it in a function...
f <- function(w){
  partialPlot(x=rf, pred.data=iris, x.var=as.character(w))
}

f(x1)
# Error in as.character(w) : 'w' is missing
```

#### Questions:

1) Where can I find the source code for `partialPlot`?

2) How is it possible to write a function which takes a string `x1` as an argument where `x1 == as.character(x1)`, but the function throws an error when `as.character` is not applied to `x1`?

3) Why does it fail when I wrap it inside a function? Is `partialPlot` messing with environments somehow?

Tips/ things to try that might be helpful for solving such questions by myself in future would also be very welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code for `partialPlot()` is found by entering

```
randomForest:::partialPlot.randomForest
```

into the console. I found this by first running

```
methods(partialPlot)
```

because entering `partialPlot` only tells me that it uses a method.  From the `methods` call we see that there is one method, and the asterisk next to it tells us that it is a non-exported function.  To view the source code of a non-exported function, we use the triple-colon operator `:::`.  So it goes

```
package:::generic.method
```

Where `package` is the package, `generic` is the generic function (here it's `partialPlot`), and `method` is the method (here it's the `randomForest` method).

Now, as for the other questions, the function can be written with `do.call()` and you can pass `w` without a wrapper.

```
f <- function(w) {
    do.call("partialPlot", list(x = rf, pred.data = iris, x.var = w))
}

f(x1)
```

This works on my machine. It's not so much environments as it is evaluation.  Many plotting functions use some non-standard evaluation, which can be handled most of the time with this `do.call()` construct.

But note that outside the function you can also use `eval()` on `x1`.

```
partialPlot(x = rf, pred.data = iris, x.var = eval(x1))
```

I don't really see a reason to check for the presence of `as.character()` inside the function.  If you can leave a comment we can go from there if you need more info. I'm not familiar enough with this package yet to go any further.

Comment: Thank you! That completely answers the question. The `partialPlot` function applies `substitute` to its argument, which is why it treats `x1` as different from `as.character(x1)`. The information you gave will be very useful to me in future as well!